# Regex Match on IP Address Before Known String

Tags: python, regex, nmap

I'm using nmap to search for hostnames and related IPs on my local (home) network. I can pull a string that looks something like this:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-02-15 22:20 PST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:11:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ (Cisco-Linksys)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.0084s latency).
MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:A1:2E:ZZ:ZZ (Apple)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.9
Host is up (0.012s latency).
MAC Address: A4:ZZ:57:17:ZZ:ZZ (Seiko Epson)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.103
Host is up (0.036s latency).
MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:6D:05:ZZ:ZZ (Apple)
```

I know that I can put together a regular expression to give me the IP address directly above the "Seiko Epson" line, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm specifically looking for a way to find the IP address of the host that I'm searching for, I'm currently using:

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

to find IP addresses, but I do not know how to augment this to find the IP address above a given string.

Comment: please put what do you want to match. Some test cases ?

Comment: For a test case, I'd like to match the IP address directly above the line that calls out "Seiko Epson". How would you handle that in regex?

Comment: How do you obtain the input string `Starting Nmap ... (Apple)` ?  If it's acceptable for you to concat it into a single long string, the task will be quite easier.

Comment: It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could make `nmap` to produce a machine-readable output instead of relying on regexes that can break easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the whole input as a single string, then

1. You firstly search for a fixed string `Nmap scan report for`,
2. nextly remember a sequence `0-9` or `.` (which should be there) as the output IP address,
3. then skip until the MAC addr part (containing `:`),
4. skip until the next opening paren,
5. and finally check if the string inside parens is `Seiko Epson`.

Example:

```
>>> inp='''Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-02-15 22:20 PST
... Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
... Host is up (0.00025s latency).
... MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:11:ZZ:ZZ:ZZ (Cisco-Linksys)
... Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
... Host is up (0.0084s latency).
... MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:A1:2E:ZZ:ZZ (Apple)
... Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.9
... Host is up (0.012s latency).
... MAC Address: A4:ZZ:57:17:ZZ:ZZ (Seiko Epson)
... Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.103
... Host is up (0.036s latency).
... MAC Address: ZZ:ZZ:6D:05:ZZ:ZZ (Apple)'''
>>> import re
>>> r1 = re.compile(r'Nmap scan report for ([0-9.]*)[^:]*[^(]*\(Seiko Epson\)')
>>> r1.search(inp).group(1)
'192.168.1.9'
```

The idea behind `[^`...`]`'s is finite state machine.